# Do you know a free program that keeps track of available software updates?

Tags: installer

i need to keep track of several softwares on my computer in a local network. All my software updates are available within this (offline) network and I am looking for a tool, that keeps track of possible updates.
The optimal way would be: The program checks every night for updates within local network and (if the corresponding program is not running), it installs those update.

One important addition: I need to keep track of my own programs. So I am looking for a tool, that can handle any program (of course i would need to fit the settings...)

I found dozends of similar software but most of them is expensive or needs internet connection or only supports a fixed list of software...

I would be so happy if anyone could help me.

Thank you!

Knust